# maximum depth of a binary tree using BFS- why is the depth doubled what it is supposed to be?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am writing iterative solution to finding the max depth of a binary tree- using `Breadth First Search (BFS)`:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

from collections import deque
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root: 
            return 0

        queue = deque()
        queue.append(root)
        depth = 1
        level_length = len(queue)

        while queue: 
            for i in range(level_length): 
                node = queue.popleft() 

                if node.left: 
                    queue.append(node.left)

                if node.right: 
                    queue.append(node.right)
                    
            depth +=1 
            
        return depth
```

For the input `root = [3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`, I am getting `output=6` rather than 3, which is clearly the correct answer.

I've gone through my code several times on paper, but can't  seem to see where it is falling short- any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the entire code, including the part where you **call** the `maxDepth` function ? And the actual output that you're getting ? Also, I'm confused about `null`.

Comment: I'm guessing that input is a representation of the full tree? Missing that build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`level_length = len(queue)` is only computed one time before the traversal begins, so it's always 1. This means your inner `for` loop never runs more than once and is effectively nonexistent, causing `depth += 1` to run on every node.

Move the length computation into the `while` so that the `for` loop runs the correct number of times for each level before incrementing `depth`.

Leetcode wants `depth = 0` instead of `depth = 1`, but you'd probably figure this out after fixing the main bug.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen- one quick question, does the 'root' node sit in depth 0 or 1 by definition? Because I found quite varying opinions on this, but according to Leetcode it sits on 0.

Comment: No problem. I don't know the definitive answer offhand but I suspect it's whatever you decide, just like array indices.